# How accurate is this classification of matter

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I've recently been starting to study chemistry.
This is how my textbook depicts classification of matter on a macroscopic level.
[image: classification of matter]

After seeing this, I was confused because wouldn't the mixtures, be it either homogeneous or heterogeneous, consist of either elements or compounds or both too?

Please help me clarify.

Comment: You missed the point. This "is" not "consist of" or "made from". So elements mean pure carbon, pure gold etc

Answer (score 0):

Heterogeneous and homogeneous mixtures consist of *many elements or compounds*. For example, salt solution is a homogeneous mixture. It is made up of compounds-sodium chloride and water; the elements in this homogeneous mixture are Na, Cl, H, O.

The sub-classification of pure substances-elements or compounds is based on elements and compounds in their pure state. Na, Cl, H or O will independently fall under the category of elements. Water and sodium chloride will independently fall under the category of compounds.